# React.useEffect() second argument default value

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

I was wondering about the `React.useEffect()` API

```
React.useEffect(() => {
  // do something only when `someVariable` change.
}, [someVariable]);
```

Or if you want it to be called every time a prop or state change.

```
React.useEffect(() => {
  // do something anytime a prop/state change
});
```

My query is on the later approach, what is the default second argument that `React.useEffect` gets that it fires every time any prop/state changes?

Answer (score 0):

So based on https://github.com/facebook/react/blob/master/packages/react/src/ReactHooks.js#L87 from the React code base, I see that the default second argument is `undefined`.

```
React.useEffect(() => {}. undefined);
```

The above will update every time a prop/state changes, basically anything that causes it to re-render.

Based on this check

```
inputs: Array<mixed> | void | null, // which means it is either an array or undefined
```

Reference: [React useEffect Code](https://github.com/facebook/react/blob/1d48b4a68485ce870711e6baa98e5c9f5f213fdf/packages/react/src/ReactHooks.js#L87)

Answer (score 0):

Since there's no second argument, it's `undefined`, and `useEffect` callback is triggered on every render:

```
React.useEffect(() => {
  // do something anytime a prop/state change
});
```

In case an array is provided as second argument, it's used as a list of values to throttle `useEffect` calls in case they aren't changed. In case an array is empty, `useEffect` callback is called once on component mount.